# Prediction of the values in simple chemical mixture calculation

Tags: analysis

I have a problem with a simple chemical calculation that has to be extended to cover predicted results that will first exist after the extended calcualtion is done.

Example data:

```
V1 = 85 ml - volume substance 1
V2 = ??? - searched volume of substance 2
C1 = 5 ng/ml - concentration of substance 1
C2 = 2000 ng/ml -concentration of substance 2
D = 50 ng/ml - my desired concentration of the new solution
```

**How the normal calculation work without extension**

```
factor = C2/D - C1/D
V2 = V1/factor
```

That is the easy part. Now in order to make the required substance with desired value of **50**.
I need to remove exact amount as V2 from my V1 before I can add the V1 back. That would be the normal case.

Instead of the "normal" case I would like to avoid that step of removing the amount of V2 from V1 and instead of that do the: **calculation that takes into account the volume that will be created when the calculated V2 is combined with V1 of the required value**. With the above formula I can't do that combining V1 with V2 without the removal of V2 will cause that the value would be litte less than 50.

Any idea which calculation could help me to do the above calculation but predicting the total volume V1 and V2 and still reaching exact concentration of D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to find volume $V_2$, with concentration $C_2$, that will be added to volume $V_1$, with concentration $C_1$, such that they together have a concentration of $D$:

$$C_1 V_1 + C_2 V_2 = D (V_1 + V_2).$$

With a few manipulations you can isolate $V_2$:

\begin{align}
C_1 V_1 + C_2 V_2 &= D (V_1 + V_2) \\
(C_2 - D) V_2 &= (D - C_1) V_1\\
V_2 &= \left(\frac{D - C_1}{C_2 - D}\right) V_1.
\end{align}

For your specific problem the value of $V_2$ is:
\begin{align}
V_2 &= \left(\frac{50 - 5}{2000 - 50}\right) \cdot 85\\
&=\frac{51}{26}.
\end{align}